# Using apk add to install a specific version of package from alpinelinux.org

Tags: package-management, nginx, alpine-linux, apk-tools

I'm trying to use nginx-mod-http-lua on Alpine v3.17-stable. I want to use [this specific 1.24.0-r2 version of the package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/aarch64/nginx-mod-http-lua) which was just released two days ago.

I'm trying `docker run -it nginx:1.24.0-alpine sh -c "apk update && apk upgrade && apk add nginx-mod-http-lua=1.24.0-r2"` but I'm seeing error:

```
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  nginx-mod-http-lua-1.22.1-r0:
    breaks: world[nginx-mod-http-lua=1.24.0-r2]
```

I'm unsure how to actually use this package listed on https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org. How can I install?

Comment: Related but also unanswered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73870089/install-alpine-package-from-alpinelinux-org

Answer (score 1):

`docker run -it nginx:1.24.0-alpine sh -c "apk add nginx-mod-http-lua=1.24.0-r2 --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main"`